# Can I say unwind instead of take a break?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Let's suppose I'm working or studying and I want to take a break.

Is "I'm going to unwind" used in that situation or is "I'm going to take a break" a lot more common?

How about

> I'm gonna take a break and unwind.

And

> I'm gonna take a break to unwind.

Thanks,

Comment: "Take a break" specifically states that you are going to stop working for a short time. What you do in that time is another matter (visit the bathroom, make a cup of tea or simply relax (unwind) for a few minutes).

Answer (score 4):

"Unwind" implies that you are currently "wound". That is you are stressed and the purpose of the break is to get rid of that stress.

Otherwise you could take a break because you are tired, or hungry, or bored (or lots of other reasons) not because you are stressed.